# comprobar si existe valor 1 (boleano) en base de datos, en update de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Laravel 8, el cual tiene una base de datos con una columna boleana, esta columna registra 0 y 1.

Adjunto la migracion de la BD:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('tipo_usuario')->default(0); //0 == editor  &&  1  == administrador
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Me gustaría realizar una comprobación en el update de la edicion de mis usuarios, para que si cambian el valor de 0 a 1 en el formulario de edicion y no existen mas valores de tipo 1 en la tabla de mysql no permita editar el formulario y devuelva al usuario a la página del indice del CRUD.

He intentado lo siguiente, pero no se como comprobar esto.

```
/**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required | email',
            'password' => 'required | min:8',
        ]);

        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->name = $request->get('name');
        $users->surname = $request->get('surname');
        $users->email = $request->get('email');
        $users->tipo_usuario = $request->get('tipo_usuario');
        $users->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));

        if ($users->tipo_usuario != null) {
            $users->update();
            return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Usuario editado correctamente.');
            
        } else {
            return redirect('/users')->with('message', 'No puede eliminar todos los administradores.');
        }
    }
```

Basicamente creo que necesitaría ayuda en esta línea para hacerla funcionar de forma adecuada:

```
if ($users->tipo_usuario != null) {
```

Para entender el funcionamiento, de lo que trato de hacer explicaré brevemente.
Tenemos usuarios administradores (valor 1) y usuarios editores (valor 0) si en el formulario de edición un administrador cambia su rol de 1 a 0 automaticamente se le desloguea de su cuenta y pasa a ser editor. Para evitar que la página quede sin administradores. Mi idea era no permitir cambiar el ultimo valor de 1 que quede en la columna por un 0 de este modo siempre hay un administrador.

También debe de poder cambiarse posteriormente los valores de 0 (editor) a
1 (administrador)

Muchísimas Gracias de antemano.

**Edit**

He probado lo siguiente, pero parece no funcionar:

```
 $admin = User::where('tipo_usuario', '=', 1)->first();
    
        if ($admin != null) {
            $users->update();
            return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Usuario editado correctamente.');
            
        } else {
            return redirect('/users')->with('message', 'No puede eliminar todos los administradores.');
        }
```

Comment: Es decir ¿con qué exista una fila con valor de 0 permitir la edición?

Comment: si, exacto, si existen filas de valor 0 se puede seguir editando, pero si modificando la columna de 1 al valor 0 dejan de existir valores 1 en esa columna que no lo permita, es decir siempre debe haber un valor 1 almenos en la columna y pueden haber tantos valores 0 como queramos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente (*a modo de ejemplo y partiendo de lo mismo pudieras ajustar*):

1. Primero debes evaluar si en los datos del request viene un valor 0 para el tipo de usuario

   ```
   if ($request->tipo_usuario === 0) { .............. }
   ```

   - Si efectivamente trae un valor 0 entonces debes proceder con lo siguiente:

     - Considero que la consulta no debe estar enfocada en encontrar los datos de un usuario específico sino en un conteo de elementos con base en una condición de evaluar si *`tipo_usuario`* es igual a 1, ya que con lo que tienes al momento no sabrías en realidad cuantos administradores quedan aún

       ```
       $conteoUsuariosAdministradores = Modelo::whereTipoUsuario(1)->count();
       ```
     - Si dicho conteo es mayor a 1 entonces permitir la actualización en caso contrario no procedería

       ```
       if ($conteoUsuariosAdministradores > 1) {
       /*
           Permitir la actualización del tipo
       */
       } else {
       /*
           No permitir la actualización
       */
       }
       ```
   - Si no trae un valor 0 para el tipo de usuario entonces permitir la actualización ya que el tipo de usuario no ha cambiado y seguiría existiendo como administrador.

Aclaración:

- Usé 0 como el valor supuesto para el tipo de usuario pero deberías ajustar según sea el caso

Comment: mmm, si deseo cambiar un 0 (editor ) a valor 1(administrador) ya no me deja, he probado a colocar >= 1 pero por supuesto deja pasar todo y no funciona

Comment: @WinterIsback por que de momento la lógica esta pensada en el escenario que planteaste en tu pregunta, si necesitas considerar lo que mencionas deberás ampliar esta propuesta de la respuesta